# Can Chisel3 be called from Java to generate Firrtl?

Tags: java, clojure, hdl, chisel

I'm trying to use Chisel3 from Clojure (a JVM language) and would like to know if there is any Java API for it, I'm having problems calling it directly from the Scala API.

And if does not exist, what alternates do I have? Would it be better to make a compiler to generete Firrtl directly from Clojure/Java?

Comment: Discussed on Gitter: https://gitter.im/freechipsproject/chisel3?at=5dbe03ba2a6494729c884959

Comment: I agree that calling a Scala API from Clojure will be tricky. I don't know if this is feasible with Firrtl, but one alternative would be to write a Java wrapper around the Scala API and call that from Clojure. The more complex the Scala API, the more difficult it is to wrap it in a Java API though.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that Clojure is a LISP dialect running on the JVM instead?